# MySQL LIMIT result with NO LIMIT distinct values

Tags: mysql, limit

I want to return a limted result for a query, but at the same time return all DISTINCT values as if no limit was set.

```
SELECT artnr, color FROM table WHERE catID=1 LIMIT 20
SELECT DISTINCT(color) FROM table WHERE catID=1
```

If a user selects all products with catID=1, this will return a limited result.
I want to show the user all possible colors for this category, so the user can select a specific color.

Can this be done in one query, or does it require seperate querys as above?

---

Let say I grab all rows without a limit. Then with php I could use an array to grab distinct color values.

SELECT artnr, color FROM table WHERE catID=1

```
$color_array = array();  
while($row... {  
 $color_array[$row["color"]];  
}  
for($a=0;$a<20;$a++) {  
  // Print 20 rows from the result  
}
```

But I want to LIMIT the result, and still grab ALL color value.

Comment: I don't get it.  Could you post some of your example data as well as the expected result?

Comment: You _really_ should do it with two separate queries.

Comment: are you running above query from DB level or from some application?

Comment: @Bader - running from db. What is comes down to is beeing able to grab filter information regarding content. I dont want to show all possible values for ie. color, only those that exists in the current selection. But maby I need two seperate queries as $lanzz say